# Excluding type from class template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently having trouble with `stack` messing up one of my templated classes.
The problem being that methods like `pusk_back`, `begin` or `end` aren't usable with that type.
So my goal here is to prevent contain from being instantiated with `stack<T>` or to add a condition preventing a `stack` instance to get to those parts of the code.
Here is what the `class` looks like:

```
template<typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
class contain {
    public:
        contain() : _container()
        {
        }
        ~contain()
        {
        }
        void push(T const&data)
        {
            this->_container.push_back(data);
        }
        void aff()
        {
            std::for_each(_container.begin(), _container.end(),
            [](T &var) {::aff(var);});
        }
        void add()
        {
            std::for_each(_container.begin(), _container.end(),
            [](T &var) {::add(var);});
        }
    private:
        U<T> _container;
};
```

I tried to specialize the template but wasn't able to find the syntax nor was I able to check the type of the variable at runtime.

Comment: What is your goal? To prevent `contain` from being instantiated with `stack<T>`? If so, you already have that, no? Because the template _can't_ be instantiated, as you've said. Or did you want to just get rid of the functions that don't work for `stack<T>`? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I think you skipped some steps in your question. How is stack involved? Are you trying to use std::stack as an adapter for this container? It explicitly violates the requirements for SequenceContainer see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've clarified my goal, I admit the question wasn't well formulated

Comment: @KennyOstrom I am actually trying to exclude stack from being the `U` parameter of the template

Comment: If you don't want that a template is instanced for a certain class, you may specialize the template for this class. So, the template specialization could provide an alternative implementation. This has been done for example with `std::vector<bool>` (although this is considered as "not so lucky idea" now).

Comment: @Scheff As said I already tried but wasn't able to do it right, maybe you could help

Comment: I tried my best. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that `template`s still appear a little bit like black magic to me. I've successfully used template specializations in various situations (if I had no better idea) but never with template arguments. So, I tried...

When I tried on coliru (compiler `g++ (GCC) 8.1.0`) I started with `-std=c++11` and soon got some terrible errors. For my luck, there was also a hint to switch to `-std=c++17`. I did and things become much better immediately. I remembered roughly that the template template arguments are not well supported in C++11. A short glance on `cppreference` proved me right:

> **[Template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)**
>
> template < parameter-list > typename (C++17) | class name(optional)           (1)
>   template < parameter-list > typename (C++17) | class name(optional) = default   (2)
>   template < parameter-list > typename (C++17) | class ... name(optional)         (3)     (since C++11)
>
> 1) A template template parameter with an optional name.
>   2) A template template parameter with an optional name and a default.
>   3) A template template parameter pack with an optional name.

Having this clarified, I took part of OPs sample code and added a partial specialization for the `template` where I

- left the first parameter
- specialized the second parameter with `std::stack`.

Actually, this is not much different to how templates with type or value arguments are specialized.

`cppreference` has an article for this **[partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)** but using the term as search key word there should be many hits for books and tutorials. (I remember the book I once learned C++ templates from mentioned this also – of course.)

So, here my small sample to demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, template <typename...> typename U>
class ContainerT {
  private:
    U<T> _container;
  public:
    ContainerT(): _container() { }
    ~ContainerT() = default;
    ContainerT(const ContainerT&) = default;
    ContainerT& operator=(const ContainerT&) = default;

    bool empty() const { return _container.empty(); }
    void push(const T &data) { _container.push_back(data); }
    T pop()
    {
      const T data = _container.back();
      _container.pop_back();
      return data;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ContainerT<T, std::stack> {
  private:
    std::stack<T> _container;
  public:
    ContainerT(): _container() { }
    ~ContainerT() = default;
    ContainerT(const ContainerT&) = default;
    ContainerT& operator=(const ContainerT&) = default;

    bool empty() const { return _container.empty(); }
    void push(const T &data) { _container.push(data); }
    T pop()
    {
      const T data = _container.top();
      _container.pop();
      return data;
    }
};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  // for std::vector
  DEBUG(ContainerT<int, std::vector> vec);
  DEBUG(vec.push(1); vec.push(2); vec.push(3));
  DEBUG(while (!vec.empty()) std::cout << vec.pop() << '\n');
  // for std::stack
  DEBUG(ContainerT<int, std::stack> stk);
  DEBUG(stk.push(1); stk.push(2); stk.push(3));
  DEBUG(while (!stk.empty()) std::cout << stk.pop() << '\n');
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

It's obvious that `ContainerT` is instanced for `ContainerT<int, std::vector>`. Otherwise, the `push()` method couldn't compile.

For the `ContainerT<int, std::stack>`, the specialization is used instead. (Again, otherwise, the `push()` method couldn't compile.)

**Output:**

```
ContainerT<int, std::vector> vec;
vec.push(1); vec.push(2); vec.push(3);
while (!vec.empty()) std::cout << vec.pop() << '\n';
3
2
1
ContainerT<int, std::stack> stk;
stk.push(1); stk.push(2); stk.push(3);
while (!stk.empty()) std::cout << stk.pop() << '\n';
3
2
1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a9aa9c72fd8711a)</kbd>